# Why can't I bind events directly to wx.Menu in Windows?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an application that allows some controllers to change the layout of the main menu bar. I do this by passing the main menu bar to the controller, then the controller adds some menus to it. My issue is binding menu click events to those added menus. It's very easy in theory:

```
def bind_main_menu_bar(self, main_menu_bar):
    self.main_menu_bar = main_menu_bar

    edit_menu = shared.create_menu([
        (const.ID_UNDO, self.LABEL_UNDO_EMPTY),
        (const.ID_REDO, self.LABEL_REDO_EMPTY),
        (),
        (const.ID_VALIDATE_ADDRESSES, 'Validate selected addresses'),
        (const.ID_VALIDATE_ALL_ADDRESSES, 'Validate all addresses'),
    ])
    edit_menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_menu)
    edit_menu.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.on_menu_update)

    main_menu_bar.Insert(1, edit_menu, 'Edit')
```

This works excellently in OSX, but in Windows, only the `wx.EVT_MENU` event works when binding the event directly to the `edit_menu` menu. In other words, the `wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI` event handler is never triggered. I've also tried binding `EVT_MENU_OPEN`, `EVT_MENU_CLOSE` and `EVT_MENU_HIGHLIGHT` but none of them work. They all work when I bind them to the top level frame, but then there is no way to limit the event handler to only the `edit_menu` menu.

Is this a bug, or is there something I'm overlooking? Also, can anybody spot a workaround to my issue?

---

*I'm using wxPython 2.9 (dev) on Window 8.*

Comment: What is `shared.create_menu`? Could you share the code or make it clear which built-in function you're referring to, please?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike's right, avoid explicit IDs -- and you don't need them (see the [wxPython Style guide in the wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Style%20Guide) for details).

Menu items are not regular Windows, so you can't do the normal event binding thing with them -- too bad.

However, when you bind the event to the frame, you can specify where the event comes from. My usual idiom for binding menu events:

```
FileMenu = wx.Menu()
item = FileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Quit")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, item)
```

In this case, `self` is a `Frame` - so you are saying: bind the `EVT_MENU` to the frame, call the `self.OnQuit` as a the callback, but only bind events from this particular menu item.

This is uglier when you are doing dynamic binding, but it should work.

Note that in this example I'm using an ID - the exception to that rule is that using standard IDs (like `wx.ID-EXIT`, `wx.ID_HELP`) is nice, because then `wx` can "do the right thing" on various platforms (like more the quite menu to the app menu on OS-X).

Comment: +1 I hadn't seriously considered binding a separate handler to each menu item. It looks like it might be the best solution though. It just seems so wasteful to me to create a ton of small 3 line methods just for the menu items. Too bad I can't specify a `wx.Menu` as the event source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you're supposed to bind menu events to the frame, not the menu items themselves. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my question: "They all work when I bind them to the top level frame, but then there is no way to limit the event handler to only the `edit_menu` menu.". It is much easier and simpler for me to just bind events directly to the edit menu than it is to bind them to the top level frame, since I've then got to be careful that no menu button IDs clash between handlers, and I have to remember to unbind all the events that I bind when I eventually remove the edit menu again.

Comment: Well you shouldn't use hard coded IDs in wx. Use wx.NewId or wx.ID_ANY

Comment: I'm using `wx.NewId` for all my IDs, but given enough menus with items I can easily imagine the ID of an item in the menu of an editor crashing with the ID of an item in the base menus. I'm using ID names like `ID_UNDO` and `ID_VALIDATE_ADDRESSES` etc, not creating a new ID per item.